# How to create a conda environment with requirements from unofficial channels?

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I am trying to create a conda environment with some required packages which are not in the official channels:

`create --name stat_learn --file requirements.txt`

However it fails with the following error:

`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:`

I am using ubuntu 18.04, but I don't think it is related to my system. Here you can find a sample requirements file to reproduce the error:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
r-plotroc=2.2.0=r34hd3e613b_0
```

Is there a way to either i) produce a requirements file with channels included that would make the creation automatic or ii) let conda search itself for unofficial channels and find the required packages?

Thank you in advance, hope the question is clear :)

Comment: What do you mean by unofficial? Is the package found if you search on https://anaconda.org?

Comment: I mean that the channel is not among the default ones that come with the conda installation (e.g. conda-forge). In the example above I installed r-plotroc from mdekstrand, so when I try to create the environment with the requirements it fails.

I know that in this case I could simply use:
`conda config --add channels mdekstrand`.

However I was wondering if it exists a more general approach.

Comment: [Use a YAML file](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually) instead of a requirements file. You can specific channels in the YAML.

Comment: Ok thank you, that would be an option. Anyway if I understood correctly it is still impractical if I have many packages to install. Is there an automatic way to build a YAML file?

Comment: If you already have an env, then `conda env export`. Otherwise, no, but you don't need to specify most packages, as they get picked up as dependencies. That is, you only need to specify the leaves of the dependency tree. If I need something completely reproducible (every dependency version documented), I first create a new env using only those leaf packages, e.g., `conda create -n rplotroc_env -c mdekstrand r-plotroc` then I export the YAML of that env (usually with the `--no-builds` flag so others can use it across platforms).